# Ordinary Differential Equation $y''(t)-6y'(t)+9y(t)=18$ with initial conditions $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, functions

$$\large \begin{cases} y''(t)-6y'(t)+9y(t)=18 \\ y(0)=2, \qquad y'(0)=1 \end{cases}$$

Step one

$$y''-6y'+9y=18$$
$$r^2-6r+9=0$$
$$(r-3)(r-3)=0$$
$$r=3$$

$$y = e^{3t}(A+Bt)$$

What is my next step since I'm given $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=1$?

Because if that wasn't given, I would just substitute $y''$ and $y'$ with zero and assume $y$ as a constant, $C$ and then solve for $C$.

Comment: You have found only the homogeneous solution. You need to compute the particular solution also.

Comment: Personally, I think [solving this IVP via Laplace Transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx) would be a lot more efficient, since you can just plug in your initial conditions immediately.

Comment: I will answer with laplace transforms for the interest of the OP after they've done it with this method. We shouldn't present two methods at once, that's bound to confuse the op.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $y=2$ is a particular solution and then the general solution is
$$ y=e^{3t}(At+B)+2. $$
Using $y(0)=2,y'(0)=1$, one has
$$ B+2=2,3B+A=1$$
from which one obtains $A=1,B=0$. So the solution is
$$ y=te^{3t}+2. $$

Answer (score 0):

You're only halfway there. The constant C will give you the particular solution, but you have yet to use the 'initial conditions' (which is $y$ and $y'$ at 0) to compute A and B.

Use the second line of the system to compute A and B, which will give you a closed form expression of the **unique solution** to the ODE.